# Uploading HTML Files to Display on Openshift PHP 5.4 Website?

Tags: php, html, git, openshift

I can't get [these html files](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PdwfE.jpg) to display AS my Openshift site.  Only the default Openshift created [index.php file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U9QPN.jpg) shows up (which I have edited; see "Test Test Test" as h1).  How do I get MY html files to appear as the HOME page, etc. when I click on my http:/php-....rhcloud.com/ domain name?

Comment: If you type `http://php-….rhcloud.com/about.html` into your browser, is one of your pages displayed?

Comment: Yes.  Only the index.php page shows up.  I can change the index.php page any way I want, and see the changes on my http://php-….rhcloud.com/about.html page.  It just appears that I cannot upload my css or html files at all even though I get "success" messages with I git add them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that you would like to replace the default `index.php`, which comes with the PHP 5.4 cartridge, with your own static `Index.html` page. To do that, simply:

1. delete the `index.php` from the repo
2. rename the `Index.html` to `index.html` (so it now starts with a lowercase `i`)
3. `git add`, `git commit` and `git push` both changes

...and your `index.html` will be rendered by the server instead as the index page when you visit your domain.

Comment: Wow, this worked.  Thank you!  Now I have to tweak the site.  Some pages aren't appearing the same at the home page as they should.